# How to update references in OnItemSelected()?

Tags: android, listener

Is it possible to update references in OnItemSelected after notifyDataSetChanged was called? 
e.g

```
ImageView onFront;
gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                onFront = (ImageView) view;

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

I am using onFront to rotate image, but after I call notifyDataSetChanged - I  cannot.

Comment: Actually what do you want to perform.. Do you want the already displayed image to be displayed even after any data change in adapter..

Comment: but if we update something and then notified it will reflect into views. Updating anything after notifying will not reflect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your code to remember which view was clicked.

```
gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                view.setTag(postion);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Then use this position in getview of adapter

```
int pos = (Integer)view.getTag();
if(pos == position){
 //Make your change in view to make it look different
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To update the reference and reflect it into view , you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. This is the only way to tell your adapter that something has changed , Who is controlling view.

Comment: But after notifydatasetchanged, onFront does not refenrece desired picture any mmore!

Answer (score 1):

Try calling this method after your method:

> listview_adapater.invalidate();

Answer (score 1):

Try to make onFront static like this.

```
private static ImageView onFront;
```